# Finding hash collision

Tags: hash, sha, hmac

for instance, sha-1 is known as weak hash function. 
If attacker finds collision in hash function, can he generate valid MAC for given message m?
I mean it is possible to generate valid mac for any message , just using weak hash function.
If it possible, what is needed to generate valid mac?

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about HMACs, and if so, no, finding a collision in a hash function isn't enough to generate a valid HMAC - you would need a collision between a hash, and that hash prepended with a specific other string, which you don't always know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefixing hash collision vulnerabilities found in MD5 and SHA-1 do not undermine the security of an HMAC.

**To put it simply**: The security of the HMAC is dependent on a secret key and generating a collision isn't a shortcut. The attacker cannot generate the intended valid HMAC without knowledge of this secret key `K`- nor any other message input that would lead to the same output (e.g. a collision).

Additionally, the vulnerability found in MD5 and SHA-1 are prefixing attacks, and an attacker cannot control the prefix of the hash used in an HMAC due to an XOR operation, as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: That diagram is somehow harder to follow than _HMAC(K, m) = H((K ⊕ opad) || H((K ⊕ ipad) || m))_.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, because the key acts as a bias adding just enough entropy to defeat the weakness. In the same way you can also still use HMACs based on md5. Obviously you shouldn't do so.